# How to change background color of Prompt box in sublime text3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Prompt box become black after change color of theme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sublime text theme 
Sublime text ---> preferences ---> color scheme ---> choose some different (choose Eiffel)

Hope it helped.
**EDIT**
Do this then,

**You'll need to edit the appropriate images within the /Packages/Theme - Default/ folder**

Comment: Thanks,I change theme but it always black.

Comment: Thank you !  I delete the line of  "theme",It become normal.